# How can I link a photo in a Facebook album to a URL

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, photo

On a Facebook page I have photos with examples of our work. I would like to link each photo to a URL with details of this work. Is there a way to link a photo that is already in a Facebook album to a URL on or outside Facebook?

Answer (score 5):

You can only do this to you own photos.  Due to recent upgrades, Facebook has made this more difficult.  To do this, go to the album page where the photo is that you want to link to.  You should see thumbnail images of the photos in the album.  Hold down the "Control" or "Command" key while clicking the photo that you wish to link to.  A new browser tab will open with the picture you clicked.  Under the picture there is a URL that you can send to others to share the photo.  You might have to have the privacy settings for that album set so that anyone can see the photos in that album.  If you don't the person who clicks the link may have to be signed in and also be your "friend."

Here is an example of one of my photos:
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=43764341&l=0d8a526a64&id=25502298  -it's my cat.

Update:

The link below the photo no longer appears.  Once you open the photo in a new tab you can right click the photo (Control+click for Mac users) and click "Copy Image URL" or similar and then share this link.  Based on my tests the person who clicks the link doesn't need to use Facebook.  The photo will load without the Facebook interface.  Like this - http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/189088_867367406856_25502298_43764341_1304758_n.jpg

Comment: It appears that this technique is not working any more either.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. This feature is not available for facebook albums.

Comment: IT WORKS FOR ME!!!   Right click the Photo and select "Copy Image Address".  That will put the URL into the clipboard.  Anyone can see the image using that URL, if the visibility is "Public". For example the URL could be https://scontent-ord1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/12509740_10154098930004156_4238803030404414226_n.jpg?oh=2cd83d9fb2236b23531ad4dcbdee2328&oe=56FB7F2B